# Function searching by name and country

Tags: c++, search

It is working when i change it to search by points or some other integer, but I have to make it to search by name and country. The function is checking the array which already has data in it.

```
void search (competitor competitors[], int number)  
{
if(number==0)
{
    cout<<"\n Array is empty!!!\n";
    return;
}

char country[50];
char name[50];
char choice;
bool flag;

do{
    cout << "\n\n Enter country: " << endl;
    cin >> country;
    cout << " Enter name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    flag = false;

    for(int i=0; i<number; i++)
    {
        if( country==competitors[i].country && name==competitors[i].name)
        {
            count << " Competitor found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)

    cout << " Want to search again(Y/N)?: ";
    cin >> choice;

}while(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
```

}

Comment: Can you confirm type of `competitors[i].country` and `competitors[i].name` ?

Comment: Besides incorrect use of the equality operator, why would anyone be using raw char arrays in C++ for user-inputted data? Just use an `std::string` and you've both fixed the buffer overflow and now have a convenient equality operator that actually compares string content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that `competitors[i].country (name)` is a `char[]`.

You cannot compare `char[]` arrays using `==` (that will compare the base addresses of the array, not the content), you must `strcmp()`. Or, as this is C++, use `std::string` instead of `char[]` and use `==`.

Comment: Yup, it was a `char[]`. Thank you. I had no idea I can not compare them.